# How long does it take for an Astronaut around the Moon to receive a spoken message from Houston?

Tags: radio-frequency

How long does it need till an Astronaut gets a spoken message from Houston and then replies to it?

What happens if there is an emergency situation where a solution has to be suggested within a time that is less than the time the message needs to be transmitted?

Comment: This is a straightforward computation (divide distance by the speed of light), and hence off-topic as homework-like. The "what if there's an emergency part" is a question about NASA (or other organization's) protocols, not about physics.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of insufficient research effort.  The calculation could easily be done by the OP.  The issue of what happens in an emergency is not a physics question; there is no indication that the OP has tried to find an answer himself, eg on the NASA website.

Answer (score 3):

The exact time depends on the orbital distance that the moon is from earth.
The commonly cited average distance between the earth & the moon is ~238,000 miles.  Light travels at ~186,282.4 miles per second.  If you used the best electronics available & sent the message via encoded light then it would take ~1.3 seconds (i.e. 238k/186k) for the message to traverse the distance one way.
Both ways would be double that time or ~2.6 seconds.

The time to send a short message & receive a short response from an astronaut would vary (depending on the length of the message); however, something short like "How are you?" & "I am fine!" would probably take less than 4 seconds total time.

re:  "What happens if there is an emergency situation where a solution has to be suggested within a time that is less than the time the message needs to be transmitted?"  There currently is no faster way to send/receive information between the earth & the moon.

Comment: @PredragLozanovski If an answer solved your problem, you can (should) accept it by clicking the pipe icon the left side. It is a reward to the answerer and it helps us to know that your problem is solved.

Comment: peterh, sorry for not having taken any action so far, the reason for which is the fact that I haven't received any post in my e-mail, so I simply forgot this topic.